# Try Catch with multiple EditTexts, Interacting with OnClick

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, try-catch

This is my first question and I have minimal experience for this personal project but i'll do my best to learn, so heres where my problem begins.

I am trying to make my app stop crashing when the EditTexts dont have user input, and so i implemented the trycatch method. However, I believe i may have badly implemented them for the 4 editTexts on the activity and broke the onClick listener from accessing the variables and calculation. The public void caudalinput does not seem to be accessed by the onClick after this restructuring.

```js
package com.example.aguavida;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class G_Inflow_Rate extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText medidoreditText;
    EditText T1editText;
    EditText T2editText;
    EditText T3editText;

    int m;
    int t1;
    int t2;
    int t3;

    public double a;
    public double result;

    public void caudalinput(View view) {

        Context context_caudal = getApplicationContext();
        String exceptionMessage = "";
        String exceptionMessage1 = "";
        String exceptionMessage2 = "";
        String exceptionMessage3 = "";

        try{
            medidoreditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medidoreditText);
            m = Integer.parseInt(medidoreditText.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            exceptionMessage = "Balde";
        }

        try{
            T1editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1editText);
            t1 = Integer.parseInt(T1editText.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            exceptionMessage1 = "time 1";
        }

        try{
            T2editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2editText);
            t2 = Integer.parseInt(T2editText.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            exceptionMessage2 = "time 2";
        }

        try{
            T3editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t3editText);
            t3 = Integer.parseInt(T3editText.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            exceptionMessage3 = "time 3";
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, exceptionMessage + " " + exceptionMessage1 + " " + exceptionMessage2 + "" + exceptionMessage3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        a = (t1 + t2 + t3)/3;
        result = m / a;

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_g__inflow__rate);

        Button gcc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gcc_button);
        gcc_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TextView gcc_result_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.g_result_textView);
                gcc_result_textView.setText(result + " ");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".G_Inflow_Rate">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Tiempo (en segundos)"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/t1editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/t2editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="tiempo 2 segundos"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/t3editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/t1editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="tiempo 1 segundos"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/t2editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/medidoreditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="litros"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/t3editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="tiempo 3 segundos"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gcc_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Litros del balde/botella"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/medidoreditText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gcc_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="Calcular"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/g_result_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="423dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:text="info"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-6dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code is below, and at this point I love love some guidance on how to proceed and structure this, because I am 100% sure that I built it very wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh sorry! This is Java from my project in Android Studio, ill change the tags and edit it.

Comment: in an anonymous class, the outer class method can access, why you say it can not access? what was the error info

Comment: I was in AS and the caudalinput was unused, sorry, I think I phrased the question badly. I don't think it can't be accessed but the int result that I need displayed is not bring passed. And it runs but I don't receive error messages, or at least don't know where to find them. I'll look this up and post it once I find out how to do that! Thank you very much

Comment: What kind of data you are giving in the edit text is it only numbers ?

Comment: Yeah, they should only be integers in this formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `try-catch` only check if the EditText data is empty or not then convert it to Integer. I have posted it for one `EditText`. You can do it for others

```
String editor =  medidoreditText.getText().toString();
m = TextUtils.isEmpty(editor) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(editor);
```